# How to solve Anaconda and Conda update NoBaseEnvironmentError?

Tags: anaconda, conda

Anaconda's current version is 1.8.7. Version 1.9.7 is now available but I cannot update it due to this error: 
NoBaseEnvironmentError.

For Conda, current is 4.6.1 and error is: 
NoBaseEnvironmentError: This conda installation has no default base environment.

I could not find any references online. Looking forward to help on this one!

Answer (score 4):

This does not work for me...

```
(py3) mac-pro : puiseux$ conda activate base
(base) mac-pro : puiseux$ conda update -n base -c defaults conda

NoBaseEnvironmentError: This conda installation has no default base environment...
```

Answer (score 1):

run the command:
`conda activate base`

you will get it